# Insert new record to array on object on a record MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a table to store users with records like this.

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "Username" : "",
    "Points" : 0,
    "CompletedAchievements" : {
        "Public": [], 
        "Private": []
    },
    "ActiveAchievements" : {
        "Public": [], 
        "Private": []
    },
    "Kudos" : [],
    "Teams" : [],
    "UserType" : "Admin",
    "PrivateAchievements": []
}
```

My C# code

```
public void Add<T>(string userId, string achievementId, int progress) {
        var collection = this.db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);

        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.And(
             Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", userId),
             Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("ActiveAchievements.Public", "Public"));

        var update = Builders<T>.Update.Push("ActiveAchievements.$.Public", new 
        ActiveAchievement() { _id = achievementId, Progress = progress });

            collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
        }
```

I am trying to add a value to the Public Array in active achievements. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: One of the issues I see is the syntax `"ActiveAchievements.$.Public"` usage in the `update` variable. `Public` is a field within the `ActiveSchievements` sub-document - and you do not need to use the `$.` when specifying the field path to add an element to the array `Public`. The following would be the right way `"ActiveAchievements.Public"`

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the filter `Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("ActiveAchievements.Public", "Public")` ?

Comment: My reasoning for the second filter was I needed the first filter to get the record and then another filter to get the ActiveAchievements array but I suppose I could go ActiveAchievements.Public and push to it directly once I’ve got the record using the first filter?

Comment: You dont need the filter on the array field _unless_ you want to search _inside_ the array for something (and that is not your intention in this case).

Comment: Got it sorted now, just needed the one filter and to get rid of the dollar sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a simple fix in the end.
Only 1 filter required the _id filter to get the record.

```
var filter = Builders<T>Filter.Eq("_id", userId);
```

Once I had that I could do the following update onto the array on the object.

```
var update = Builders<T>.Update.Push("ActiveAchievements.Public", new 
        ActiveAchievement() { _id = achievementId, Progress = progress });
```